# Articles, can you help me and give me more examples

Tags: articles

When to use "the" and not to use "the" of the structure of "of"

E.g.:

> The flickers of an eyelid
> The evolution of words

I saw these examples on Oxford Dictionary and I'm confused.

Comment: You will need a little more context.

Comment: Are you asking for the rules about what article to use in structures like *[ ____ noun + "of" + noun ]*?

Comment: And rules vary by location: "going to hospital" (UK) vs. "going to the hospital" (US). Generally speaking, English uses the definite article *very* often, so it is perhaps easier to learn the cases where it is *not* used.

Comment: Eyelids usually flicker together: The flickers of eyelids. I doubt you or anyone can flicker one at a time. Tip: the evolution of **a** word is not the evolution of word**s**.

Answer (score 0):

Articles are similar to adjectives because they describe nouns. The sentence structure:

_____ of ______

almost requires the use of an article or, frequently, a number.

> The flicker of a flame.

> The blink of an eye.

> The evolution of language.

> A comedy of errors.

> Three slices of pizza.

So when in doubt, use am article.

You might see something like:

> League of Nations

but that's more of a title. If you put it in a sentence, you would prefix it with an article:

> The League of Nations met .....

> A League of Nations is ....